# RDS Replication Error (Apply Error 1406 / Truncation)

Tags: mysql, replication, errors, amazon-rds

I have a MySQL RDS instance as a master, created a Read Replica from it, and ran some schema change operations on it.  To be specific, I changed the charset and collation of all the tables and columns from utf8 to utf8mb4.  Things were replicating fine, but an error just occurred.

`Apply Error 1406: Error; Data too long for column... etc`

This is due to lowering the varchar length on some columns from 255 to 191.

I read that you can run some commands to skip replication errors, as described here:  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/mysql_rds_skip_repl_error.html

However, would this "skip" the insert, or, just truncate the data and proceed with the insert?

I'd like the data to be truncated and still added to the table rather than aborting the entire operation, but I'm not sure if that is going to happen or not.  Any suggestions would be welcome!

Comment: Some setting is causing the Error instead of just a Warning.

Comment: You made schema changes on the replica, directly?

Comment: Yeah, the schema changes were made on the replica.

Answer (score 0):

Get 5.6.3 (or later).  As I understand it, these need to be applied to the Replica:

```
SET GLOBAL innodb_file_format=Barracuda;
SET GLOBAL innodb_file_per_table=ON;
ALTER TABLE tbl ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC; -- or COMPRESSED
```

That should allow you to keep 255 (instead of 191), thereby avoiding the truncation.

Comment: I did this but ran into a duplicate key replication error.  I've seen this error on our master, most likely due to an application error.  Since this happened on the slave, it looks like it stopped replicating.

Comment: Dup key occurred when you lowered it to 191?

Comment: Yes, exactly.  After the schema changes.

Comment: After which schema change?  Shrink to 191, where you could expect truncated text and/or dup keys?  Or after `ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC`?

Comment: After the truncation change to 191

Comment: That implies that you had some strings that agreed to 191 characters, but differed after that.  Plan A: go back to 255 and use the changes I suggest.  Plan B:  Decide what to do about the truncation (lost data).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at **slave_type_conversions** parameter in your parameter group on the replica.  There's an option to allow truncation due to data type difference between master and replica.  Please note this is a static parameter, so it will require a reboot of the RDS instance to take effect.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-options-slave.html#sysvar_slave_type_conversions

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication-features-differing-tables.html